# fbml application error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml

the form is hosted on my website,when the user submit the form,i want to pass the data to my facebook app.
how to do that

Comment: Trying removing the app from your privacy settings and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(!$user) {
       $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => "publish_stream,user_photos,friends_photos"));

    die("<script> top.location.href='".$login_url."'</script>");

}
```